# unable to pass argument from ksh script to subroutine in .pm file

Tags: perl

i have a .pm file named Util. and a subroutine that returns a next date.

```
sub getNextDate { 
    $inputDate = @_[1]; 
    if ($inputDate != "") { 
        ($year,$mon,$day) = split("-",$inputDate); 
        $mon = $mon - 1; 
        $dtToday = timelocal(0,0,0,$day,$mon,$year); 
    } else { 
        $dtToday = time; 
    } 
    $nextDate = $dtToday + 86400; 
    $nextMonth = ( localtime( $nextDate)->mon ) + 1; 
    $nextYear = ( localtime( $nextDate)->year ) + 1900; 
    $nextDay = localtime( $nextDate)->mday;
    if($nextMonth <= 9) { 
        $nextMonth = '0'.$nextMonth; 
    }
    if($nextDay <= 9) { $nextDay = '0'.$nextDay ; }
    return $nextYear . "-" . $nextMonth . "-" . $nextDay; 
}
```

I have a .ksh file. i want to pass a date as an argument from the .ksh file to the subroutine in .pm.

my code in .ksh is

```
startDate=2013-02-25 perl -MUtil -e 'print Util::getNextDate("$startDate");' > $result
echo $result
```

its not working..i am getting output based on current date rather than the date i am passing..

if i keep date directly instead of variable, i am getting correct output. `perl -MUtil -e 'print Util::getNextDate("2013-02-25");'`

But I want to use `$startDate` instead of `2013-02-25`.....please help

Comment: You use `cat "$result"` to display a file, or perhaps `... | tee "$result"` to save and display it at the same time.

Comment: ... provided `$result` contains a valid file name; you don't show us what you are setting it to, and how.

Comment: You should try indentation, it will make your life easier.

Comment: You should know that `if ($inputDate != "")` does not do what you think. `!=` is the *numeric* inequality operator, which converts both its parameters to numbers. You do not seem to be using `use warnings`, otherwise you would get a warning about this. You should probably use `if ( defined $inputDate )`.

Comment: Your code will fail because of DST. Not all days have 86400 seconds. getNextDate will return the current date sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

You use `$ENV{"startDate"}` to access an environment variable from Perl.

Perhaps it would be more usable to pass it in as `$ARGV[0]`, though.

```
startDate=2013-02-25
perl -MUtil -e 'print Util::getNextDate($ARGV[0]);' "$startDate" |
tee "$result"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) for this purpose. It has been a core Perl module since version 9.5 and so shouldn't need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

sub getNextDate {
  my $date = @_ ? Time::Piece->strptime($_[0], '%Y-%m-%d') : localtime;
  return ($date + ONE_DAY)->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
}

print getNextDate('2012-12-31'), "\n";
print getNextDate, "\n";
```

**output**

```
2013-01-01
2013-10-21
```

Answer (score 1):

this was [cross-posted to perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1059005)

and as I told you there, its not a perl but a ksh problem, you're getting variable interpolation in quotes wrong, swap ' and " when calling Perl.

```
startDate='2013-02-25'; 
perl -MUtil -e "print Util::getNextDate('$startDate');"
```

At the moment you are only passing the variable name as a string.

Comment: Code generation is almost always a bad solution. Won't be a real problem in this case, but I still recommend passing the date as an argument or env var. `perl -MUtil -le'print Util::getNextDate($ARGV[0]);' "$startDate"`